# Applying a function in a dataframe column with rows that have inconsistent content

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda

I have this dataframe:

```
      data          
0   [dic_inside_list_1]
1   [dic_inside_list_2]  
...
```

Where:

```
dic_inside_list_1 = [{'tipo': 'ATIVA', 'nome': 'GABRIEL FRANCISCO DA CUNHA', 'advogado': False, 'advogados': [{'tipo': 'ADVOGADO_PARTE_ATIVA', 'nome': 'PATRICIA DE SIQUEIRA MANOEL DUARTE', 'advogado': True}]}]

dic_inside_list_2 = [{'tipo': 'ATIVA', 'nome': 'JOSÉ FRANCISCO DE OLIVEIRA', 'advogado': False, 'advogados': [{'tipo': 'ADVOGADO_PARTE_ATIVA', 'nome': 'JULIO TORSO ALCANTARA', 'advogado': True}]}, {'tipo': 'PASSIVA', 'nome': 'INDUSTRIAS MENTEN DE CARTONAGEM LTDA', 'advogado': False, 'advogados': []}]
```

I want to create two new columns: "parte_passiva" and "parte_ativa"
"parte_ativa" is getting "nome" from the dictionary that has "tipo" as "ATIVA"
"parte_passiva" is getting "nome" from the dictionary that has "tipo" as "PASSIVA"

So it should look like this:

```
                   data                    parte_ativa             parte_passiva
0   [dic_inside_list_1]   'GABRIEL FRANCISCO DA CUNHA'     
1   [dic_inside_list_2]   'JOSÉ FRANCISCO DE OLIVEIRA'    'INDUSTRIAS MENTEN DE CARTONAGEM LTDA'
...
```

The following code worked for "parte_ativa" since that's present in both dictionaries:

```
df['parte_ativa']=df['data'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['nome'] if x[0]['tipo']=='ATIVA' else x)
```

However when I try to apply that to parte_passiva `df['parte_passiva']=df['data'].apply(lambda x: x[1]['nome'] if x[1]['tipo']=='PASSIVA' else x)` it raises an error since not all rows have `'tipo' == 'PASSIVA'`

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for that?
I know that it is not possible to put a try sentence inside lambda. Is there a way to use if sentences to prevent that from happening?

Comment: You could instead write out a function with a try block, and pass the function in to the `apply` method.

Comment: with your example, if you replace the 1 by -1 such as: `lambda x: x[-1]['nome'] if x[-1]['tipo']=='PASSIVA' else '')` it works, but not sure it will be enough for your real case. And after the `else`, put `''` or you will get the cell from the column 'data' in it!

Comment: @JohnKarasinski not sure if I understood it correctly. The way I'm picturing it won't work in scale

Comment: @abutremutante the thing is you check for 'tipo' == 'ATIVA' only in the first dictionary of your list, what if it's in the second? and what if there is no dictionary, your method for the column 'parte_ativa' will break too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs when it tries to do `x[1]`. Not all of your rows have a length of two. `dic_inside_list_2[1]` gives the `IndexError`.

If your data are lists of length 1 or 2 (only) and you're checking `'tipo'=='PASSIVA'` only at `x[1]`, you can use:

```
df['parte_passiva']=df['data'].apply(
    lambda x: x[-1]['nome'] if x[-1].get('tipo', None)=='PASSIVA' else None)
```

If your data are lists of variable length but you're still checking `'tipo'=='PASSIVA'` only at `x[1]`, you can use:

```
df['parte_passiva']=df['data'].apply(
    lambda x: x[min(len(x)-1,1)]['nome'] if x[min(len(x)-1,1)].get('tipo', None)=='PASSIVA' else None)
```

I used `x[-1].get('tipo', None)` to avoid the `KeyError` if `'tipo'` were absent from the dictionary, but `x[-1]['tipo']` is fine.